# Add new column to pandas dataframe when columns used in conditions may be variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to add a 'Status' column to my Pandas df that checks multiple columns of the df in order to display a message about possible options for the user.  I think I could do this if the columns were static but the next time a new tool is brought on line it will show up in the data as a new column that will need to be checked.  I'm trying to avoid hardcoding in specific tool names.

I figured a way to conditionally create a column for each tool that works well but it creates one for each tool.  In the above case I need one column instead of multiple.

Here's how I'm managing to create a new column based on all the tools that are in the dataframe:

```
tools = unded[unded.columns[unded.columns.str.contains("tool")]]
undedtools = tools.columns.values.tolist()


for tool in undedtools:
    unded.loc[(unded[tool] == 'Y') & (unded['lines_down'] == 'N'), tool + '_format'] = 2
    unded.loc[(unded[tool]) == 0, tool + '_format'] = 3
```

This creates a column for each tool named like "tool123_format".  The columns get filled in with a number which I use for formatting a report.  So now that I have a column like this for each tool I need to check all of these columns and report on the status.

I would expect it to report something like "tool123 and tool456 are open" if it finds a 2 in the format column for each of those tools.  Then the next line may have no open tools so it would say "All paths are closed.  Escalate to eng"

How do I get the tool names conditionally into this "Status" column for each row of the dataframe?  I had previously had this whole thing in SQL but I'm getting tired of adding dozens of new lines to my CASE WHEN statement each time we add a new tool.

Comment: I'm getting something close to part of it using this: `opentools = (tools == "Y").apply(lambda y: tools.columns[y.tolist()].tolist(), axis=1)` but I'm not sure the best way to make use of it.  As is I get a series which I can put in a column in the original df but I'm getting stuck after that.  I also tried it as a dictionary of lists.